# Express Failing in res.redirect()

Tags: node.js, express

An API made with Express (it's a large API) is producing something I dont request when making a redirect. I have this route:

```
router.get("/",  ({ conn, query }, res) => {
res.redirect('www.google.com');
}

module.exports = router;
```

Redirection is made, but to this URL: http://localhost:3000/www.google.com, when I need it to be made to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

What could be the problem? Something with CORS? A misconfiguration in Router()?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a complete URL:

```
res.redirect('https://www.google.com');
```

When you use a partial URL, the browser interprets that as a relative URL and attempts to apply the missing portions of the URL from the current web page's URL.